# Converting a text processing code written in awk to python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, awk, text-processing

The following code snippet transforms a text file into another text file, but with separators added after the specified field widths.

`gawk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="1 26 1 26 26 26 26 18 2 5 4 7 10 16 4 4 10 2 6 1 1 1 1 10 10 4 11 3 1 1 2 10 10 10 1 1 10 20 10 1 1 1 1 15 16 10 50 13 1 60"}{print $1 "|" $2 "|" $3 "|" $4 "|" $5 "|" $6 "|" $7 "|" $8 "|" $9 "|" $10 "|" $11 "|" $12 "|" $13 "|" $14 "|" $15 "|" $16 "|" $17 "|" $18 "|" $19 "|" $20 "|" $21 "|" $22 "|" $23 "|" $24 "|" $25 "|" $26 "|" $27 "|" $28 "|" $29 "|" $30 "|" $31 "|" $32 "|" $33 "|" $34 "|" $35 "|" $36 "|" $37 "|" $38 "|" $39 "|" $40 "|" $41 "|" $42 "|" $43 "|" $44 "|" $45 "|" $46 "|" $47 "|" $48 "|" $49 "|" $50}'` 
I have a few ways in mind as to how it can be converted to python, but I need a direction I should head to. Thanks in advance!

Comment: oof, that's painful to read. `gawk 'BEGIN{OFS="|"; FIELDWIDTHS="..."} {$1=$1} 1'` is a little easier on the eyes.

Comment: You're expected to make an attempt to solve the problem, and ask questions when you get stuck. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function does the same thing as the gawk snippet does-

`def chunkstring(string, lengths):
        return (string[pos:pos+length]
        for idx,length in enumerate(lengths)
        for pos in [sum(map(int, lengths[:idx]))])
column_lengths = [1,26,1,26,26,26,26,18,2,5,4,7,10,16,4,4,10,2,6,1,1,1,1,10,10,4,11,3,1,1,2,10,10,10,1,1,10,20,10,1,1,1,1,15,16,10,50,13,1,60]`